How to handle take photo from a Webview Android Jetpack compose
I am trying to use a Webview to do things like upload a verification document.
Here is what I did:

Graint Camera permission
Prepare the provider path
Override onShowFileChooser
Set fileChooserCallback?.onReceiveValue(arrayOf(uri))


  var fileChooserCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null
  var selectImage by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
  }
...
  override fun onShowFileChooser(webView: WebView?, filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?, fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?): Boolean {
        filePathCallback?.onReceiveValue(null)
        fileChooserCallback = filePathCallback
        selectImage = true
        return true
      }
...

if (selectImage) {
    ImageSelectionBottomSheet {
      if (it != null) {
        fileChooserCallback?.onReceiveValue(arrayOf(it))
        selectImage = false
      }
    }
  }

And here is incase you want to take a look:

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ImageSelectionBottomSheet(
  onDismiss: (Uri?) -> Unit
) {

  val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
  val context = LocalContext.current
  var takePictureFile: File? = null
  var takePictureUri: Uri? = null

  val grantState by remember {
    mutableStateOf(permissions.all {
      ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    })
  }

  val singlePhotoPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(),
    onResult = { uri ->
      Timber.tag("ok").d("ImageSelectionBottomSheet: %s", uri)
      onDismiss.invoke(uri)
    }
  )

  val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()
  ) { success ->
    Timber.tag("ok").d("ImageSelectionBottomSheet: %s $success", takePictureUri)
    if (success) {
      onDismiss.invoke(takePictureUri)
    }
  }

  val permissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(),
    onResult = {
      if (!it.containsValue(false)) {
        takePictureFile = createImageCaptureFile(context)
        Timber.tag("ok").d("ImageSelectionBottomSheet: %s", takePictureFile?.absoluteFile)
        takePictureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "${context.packageName}.fileprovider", takePictureFile!!)
        Timber.tag("ok").d("ImageSelectionBottomSheet: %s", takePictureUri)
        cameraLauncher.launch(takePictureUri)
      }
    }
  )

  ModalBottomSheet(
    content = {
      Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        content = {
          ActionButton(
            iconDrawableRes = com.liquidity.core.ui.R.drawable.ic_camera,
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.open_gallery),
            onClick = {
              singlePhotoPickerLauncher.launch(
                PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly)
              )
            },
          )
          Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
          ActionButton(
            iconDrawableRes = com.liquidity.core.ui.R.drawable.ic_camera,
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.take_a_new_photo),
            onClick = {
              if (grantState) {
                takePictureFile = createImageCaptureFile(context)
                takePictureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "${context.packageName}.fileprovider", takePictureFile!!)
                cameraLauncher.launch(takePictureUri)
              } else {
                permissionLauncher.launch(permissions)
              }
            },
          )
          Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
        }
      )
    },
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
    onDismissRequest = {
      onDismiss.invoke(null)
    }
  )
}


private fun createImageCaptureFile(context: Context): File {
  val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
  val fileName = "JPEG_${timeStamp}.jpg"
  val cacheDir = context.cacheDir
  return File(cacheDir, fileName)
}


The problem that I am facing:

The webview doing nothing after the bottom sheet closes.
So I don't know if it is the right approach because after taking a photo, nothing happens then.

Thanks for your attention!

Can not get the Uri after take the picture (I got it null) Which uri? Does not the variable have a name?

takePictureUri on ImageSelectionBottomSheet, I checked it on cameraLauncher result

Oh, my mistake, I did not assign value for takePictureUri after taking a picture. I just updated it.
